# Where windows show programatically connected BT devices those are unparied

Tags: bluetooth

I have a code that connect to windows bluetooth. We do not expelicity pair the device from windows wizard.
So from software when the device is connected via bluetooth, it does not show anywhere in windows list that this BT device is now connected.
Is there any way to see unparied but connected BT devices in Windows 10?

We are connecting BT device from program and trying to see where it shows in Windows 10 as connected.
It only shows paird devices but not showing unparied connected BT devices via a program

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think that a Bluetooth device must be paired before it can actually get connected. So a list of *unpaired but connected Bluetooth devices* would always turn out empty? Can you add more detail how you are connecting devices from your code?